# How to select a column if it is used twice by the use of two JOINS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

Table Sport contains 2 columns with IDTeam (together these numbers represent a soccermatch like Milan - Liverpool).

Table Team contains the teamnames corresponding with the numbers in IDteam (Milan and Liverpool in this case).

I want to make a query which shows a list of matches by selecting the names corresponding to the IDTeam's.

If I use SELECT  team.name I get several syntax errors.
If I use SELECT  * I get no syntax errors although many columns I don't want to see.

How can i just select the two columns?

```
SELECT  team.name

FROM [dbo].[Sport]

    left join  Team t ON    (t.IDTeam =Sport.HomeTeamID)    
    left join  Team t_ ON  (t_.IDTeam =Sport.ForeignTeamID);
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `inner join`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the alias:

```
SELECT  t.name, t_.name
FROM Sport S
left join  Team t  ON t.IDTeam = S.HomeTeamID 
left join  Team t_ ON t_.IDTeam = S.ForeignTeamID;
```

I also recommend to use better aliases, like th and tf.

Comment: thanks James, it seems the right direction to me, although i still get red underlined code. The columnname in Team is 'name' indeed.

Comment: Intellisense doesn't always update correctly and you can get working code underlined. Try to run it instead.

Comment: Thanks i see it works perfect! (I executed the query in the incorrect environment).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need join sport to team twice , try this with one join

```
select max(case
              when t.IDTeam = S.HomeTeamID then
               t.name
              else
               null
           end) as HomeTeamName,
       max(case
              when t.IDTeam = S.ForeignTeamID then
               t.name
              else
               null
           end) as ForeignTeamName
  from Sport S
  left join Team t on (t.IDTeam = S.HomeTeamID or t.IDTeam = S.ForeignTeamID)
```